# Função delete mata sessão no laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

Ao deletar um usuário selecionado, sem ser o usuário logado no momento, a função `modeloReferenciadoPorObjeto->delete()` do *Laravel* está finalizando a sessão do usuário logado.

```
public function deletar($id)
{
    $usuarioRecuperado = $this->user->find($id);
    //aqui consigo selecionar o usuário que desejo deletar tranquilamente
    $deletarUsuario = $usuarioRecuperado->delete();
    return view('painel.home.user.index');
}
```

No projeto foi utilizado o *auth* que já vem no *Laravel*, gerado a partir do seu comando.

A única coisa alterada foi em `Auth\RegisterController`. No método construtor foi modificado para o `$this->middleware('auth');`.

Assim se parte da premissa que somente pode cadastrar se estiver logado no sistema.

Comment: `Auth::logout();` não resolve seu problema?

Answer (score 0):

O problema que estava acontecendo é que a função `register()` na classe `RegisterUser` ao cadastrar um usuário o mesmo era automaticamente logado no sistema, e sempre eu cadastrava e tentava deletar. A sessão do usuário era atualizada para aquele usuário que tinha acabado de fazer o cadastro, quando era chamado a função `delete()` então deletava o usuário logado e não os outros então eu apenas alterei para isso não acontecer na função `register()`

```
public function register(Request $request)
  {
     $usuarios = User::all();
     $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

     event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

    // $this->guard()->login($user);

     //return $this->registered($request, $user)
                    //?: redirect($this->redirectPath());

     //depois disso apenas compactei o usuário atual da sessão e enviei para a view
     return view('painel.home.user.index', compact("usuarios"));
  }
```